# Change file names in formulas based on vlookup criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My main data set has data with country names in column A. I also have separate files for each country.

I can make a separate vlookup table where based on the country names where I have copied the file names which ends in -USA.sxlsx or -UK.xlsx or -RU.xlsx and everything else is same.

How can I have the vlookup or anything else change it based on my main data set containing the country codes?

Comment: How can you have the vlookup or anything change what?

Comment: Have a look at `SUBSTITUTE` : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332

Comment: You can build formulae or references using indirect().